# Current line after :3,7call XYZ()

Tags: command-line, range

Executing`:3,7y` does not change the line which contains the cursor (`line('.')`). This is what I expected.

However, when I execute `:3,7call XYZ()`, the current line goes to the third line. I didn't expect this behavior.

Why is that? Can I change the behavior so that the current line does not change?

Comment: Read `:help :call`. This behaviour is explained there. It doesn't say how to keep the cursor on the original line though.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to pass current line as function argument. But `line('.')` is evaluated for first line of range, thus this needs to be done earlier. My solution to this would be to use user command. Below complete sample code:

```
function XYZ(curline) range
  [normal body]
  exe "normal " . a:curline . "gg"
endfunction

command -range XYZ :let l=line('.') | <line1>,<line2>call XYZ(l)
```

That way you need to do `:3,7XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) provides (among others) a `:KeepView` command. With it, you can wrap any other command invocation, and it will maintain the current position in the buffer.

```
:KeepView 3,7call XYZ()
```